# How does a "Tiger Tree Hash" handle data whose size isn't a power of two?

Tags: hash, hash-tree

Constructing a [hash tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_tree) is simple enough if the data fits into a number of blocks that is a power of two.

```
root = H(H(A+B)+H(C+D))
         /            \ 
   H(A+B)             H(C+D)
   /    \              /   \
  A      B            C     D
```

In other cases, there is some flexibility. The missing blocks could be replaced with zeroes...

```
root = H(H(A+B)+H(C+0))
         /            \ 
   H(A+B)             H(C+0)
   /    \              /   \
  A      B            C     0
```

...passed up the tree...

```
root = H(H(A+B)+C)
         /      |
   H(A+B)       |
   /    \       |
  A      B      C
```

...hashed up the tree...

```
root = H(H(A+B)+H(C))
         /       |
   H(A+B)       H(C)
   /     \       |
  A       B      C
```

...or something different...

```
root = H(H(A)+H(B+C))
         /       |
      H(A)     H(B+C)
      /        /    \
     A        B      C
```

...and I'm just assuming that they do anything else like padding incomplete blocks before hashing.

The term "Tiger Tree Hash" seems to be used to refer to the root of a specific type of [Tiger](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiger_%28cryptography%29)-based hash tree, but I haven't been able to find the details documented anywhere. How are such hashes constructed?

Comment: You might want to rephrase that question, because a tree hash can be implemented any way you like.

Comment: @HenrickHellström Edited a bit to clarify my meaning; I'm asking about the implementation called "Tiger Tree Hash"/TTH in peer-to-peer protocols, not about Tiger-based hash trees in general.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Tree Hash EXchange format (THEX) spec](http://web.archive.org/web/20081227123433/http://open-content.net/specs/draft-jchapweske-thex-02.html) (which seems to have dropped off the web, but is still available on archive.org) says, in section 2:

> #### 2.1 Hash Functions
>
> The strength of the hash tree construct is only as strong as the
>   underlying hash algorithm. Thus, it is RECOMMENDED that a secure hash
>   algorithm such as SHA-1 be used as the basis of the hash tree.
>
> In order to protect against collisions between leaf hashes and
>   internal hashes, different hash constructs are used to hash the leaf
>   nodes and the internal nodes. The same hash algorithm is used as the
>   basis of each construct, but a single '1' byte in network byte order,
>   or 0x01 is prepended to the input of the internal node hashes, and a
>   single '0' byte, or 0x00 is prepended to the input of the leaf node
>   hashes.
>
> Let H() be the secure hash algorithm, for example SHA-1.
>
> ```
> internal hash function = IH(X) = H(0x01, X)
>
> leaf hash function = LH(X) = H(0x00, X)
> ```
>
> #### 2.2 Unbalanced Trees
>
> For trees that are unbalanced -- that is, they have a number of leaves which is not a power of 2 -- interim hash values which do not have a sibling value to which they may be concatenated are promoted, unchanged, up the tree until a sibling is found.
>
> For example, consider a file made up of 5 segments, S1, S2, S3, S4, and S5.
>
> ```
>                      ROOT=IH(H+E)
>                       /        \
>                      /          \
>               H=IH(F+G)          E
>               /       \           \
>              /         \           \
>       F=IH(A+B)       G=IH(C+D)     E
>       /     \           /     \      \
>      /       \         /       \      \
> A=LH(S1)  B=LH(S2) C=LH(S3)  D=LH(S4) E=LH(S5)
> ```
>
> In the above example, E does not have any immediate siblings with which to be combined to calculate the next generation. So, E is promoted up the tree, without being rehashed, until it can be paired with value H. The values H and E are then concatenated, and hashed, to produce the ROOT hash.

Comment: I just want to emphasize that the difference between inner and leaf hashing is very important. for security.

Comment: I have inquired further about this point here: [What is the purpose of using different hash functions for the leaves and internals of a hash tree?](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-different-hash-functions-for-the-leaves-and-interna)