# What is the reason to separate domains in the internal hash algorithm of a merkle tree hash?

Tags: hash, authentication, collision-resistance, hash-tree

From [rfc 6962](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6962) It is stated that:

> Note that the hash
> calculations for leaves and nodes differ.  This domain separation is
> required to give second preimage resistance.

That means that whenever the hash computes on leaves a distinct known element is preappend to the element $e$: $$H(0\mathbin\|e)$$ and whenever hash applied to parent nodes for leaves $h_0=H(0\mathbin\|e_0)$ $h_1=H(0\mathbin\|e_1)$ then $1$ is being put in the beggining:

$$h_2=H(1\mathbin\|h_0\mathbin\|h_1)$$

It is not clear what is the security implication if $0,1$ is not appended to the hash to separate the two domains. The authors state that this happens to prevent second-preimage attacks. But from Merkle tree hash we require from the hash function $H$ to be collision-resistant

Comment: A similar question has been asked and answered here: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2106/what-is-the-purpose-of-using-different-hash-functions-for-the-leaves-and-interna

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The document you refer to describes a method for hashing lists of data entries. Assume you do not prepend $0$ or $1$. Then, the hash for the list $(e_1, e_2)$ is $H(h_1 \| h_2)$ for $h_1 = H(e_1)$ and $h_2 = H(e_2)$. It is now easy to find a second preimage of that, namely the "list" with the single entry $h_1 \| h_2$, which will be hashed to $H(h_1 \| h_2)$.

This attack does not work if you pretend $0$s and $1$s as suggested: The hash of the list $(e_1, e_2)$ is then $H(1 \| h_0 \| h_1)$ for $h_0 = H(0 \| e_0)$ and $h_1 = H(0 \| e_1)$. You now cannot easily find a preimage of that: The single entry list $h_1 \| h_2$ gets hashed to $H(0 \| h_0 \| h_1)$, and $1 \| h_0 \| h_1$ gets hashed to $H(0 \| 1 \| h_0 \| h_1)$.

Comment: I do not understand why it is now 'easy'.  What you describe as an attack in the first paragraph is not an attack... The publicly known $h_1||h_2$ is hashed to a value. You did not show that you can find other $h'$, whereby $H(h')=H(h_1||h_2)$ So how you treat that as an attack?

Comment: I found another List, namely $(h_1 \| h_2)$ that is hashed to the same value as the list $(e_1, e_2)$. I don't have to (and cannot) find a collision for $H$ itself, but for the scheme built from $H$ for hashing lists.

Comment: but that will change the height of the tree, which will be detactable in the verification phase, so that attack is not valid...

Comment: What do you mean "detectable in the verification phase"? The reference describes a method for building a hash function MTH for hashing lists. The two lists I've described above are different and are hashed to the same value. Therefore, this is a second-preimage attack on MHT. The height of the tree or other internal details are not included in the output of MHT and are therefore not relevant for this attack.

Answer (score 3):

I believe that the issue is not what we normally call a second preimage attack on the hash function, but is actually a forgery attack on the system.

Suppose that the leaf hash was $H(e)$, and that the Merkle node hash was $h_2 = H(h_0 || h_1)$.

In that case, if we see a valid signature that involves a Merkle node computation $h_2 = H(h_0 || h_1)$, we can immediately generate a signature for the message $h_0 || h_1$ (as $h_2$ is the leaf hash for that message, and we can just copy the rest of the authentication path.

While $h_0 || h_1$ might not be an interesting message to forge, it is nevertheless a good idea to eliminate that possibility anyways.

Comment: It is not clear to me. Why $h_0||h_1$ can be forged and not $0||h_0||h_1$?

Comment: Do you mean  the adversary can plug into a new tree the value $H(h_0||h_1)$ as a leaf node, and claim a valid hash tree? If that is the case what prevents him from computing the value $H(0||h_0||h_1)$ and plug it into the new tree, which is a valid hash?

Comment: If that is the case then the new forged tree won't be of the same length of the original one, so the will be captured in the verification phase

Comment: @curious: this attack does not work against the RFC; the attacker could compute the value $H(0||h_0||h_1)$, however what he has the authentication path for is $H(1 ||h_0||h_1)$; and so he can't generate an authentication path for the value he has.  Yes, the new forged tree won't be the same length; however I believe that the RFC has variable height Merkle trees, hence the attacker submitting a shorting tree isn't an issue.

Answer (score 2):

A contextual explanation is typically easier to understand with this attack.

Suppose the underlying data structure being hashed was `User` data,  with a respective `firstName`, `middleName`, `lastName` and `age`.

The resultant merkle-tree might look something like:

$$
root = H(a || b)
\\
\overbrace{a = H(c || d), b = H(e || f)}
\\
\overbrace{c = H(first), d = H(middle)}
\overbrace{e = H(last), f = H(age)}
$$

If your verification algorithm/data is unbounded, an attacker could omit $age$ and trick the verifier into thinking $f = H(age)$ is the `User`'s actual age.
This attack wouldn't make much sense against a `firstName`,  as the binary data of $c = H(firstName)$ likely isn't human-readable.

However, if `age` de-serialized in such a way that any remaining bytes were discarded, an attacker could find a value that is plausible,  and still verifiable.

A mitigation against this is to either use an alternative hash algorithm for leaf nodes such that:

$$H(leaf) \ne H'(leaf)$$

This can also be done by defining $H^L = H(0 || leaf)$ and $H^I = H(1 || leaf)$,  where $H^L$ is the leaf hash, and $H^I$ is the inner hash.