# How to require possession of arbitrary data to decrypt a file?

Tags: encryption, proof-of-possession

I have pairs of files *A* and *B* both of arbitrary size and contents (for any pair of files, *A* could be significantly larger than *B* or vice versa). I want to be able to 'encrypt' *A* in such a way that I can distribute it openly, but so that *only* people already in possession of the entirety of *B* can access any part of *A* regardless of the contents or size of either file (disregarding things like compression or cases where *B* is trivial enough to be guessed). I don't mind distributing additional data *C* in case it's necessary for a scheme to function, but I cannot affect the contents of *B*. It must not be possible to recover any part of *B* from the encrypted *A*.

I have a strong feeling this is not possible, but I thought I'd ask before giving up. I have only extremely rudimentary knowledge of cryptography and entropy, so I apologize if this is a very silly question. One alternative I'm aware of is moving verification to distribution itself where *Proof of Possession* of *B* can be required before allowing access to *A*, but this wouldn't be optimal for my purposes.

Comment: Just how strictly do you interpret "possession of the entirety of *B*"? In particular, is it acceptable if someone in possession of *B* (but not *A*) can generate a "decryption token" *T* that someone else can use to decrypt *A*, but which does not contain enough information to reconstruct all of *B*? What about if generating the token *T* requires the possession of both *A* and *B*? (Basically, if you allow at least the latter, then the hash / MAC based schemes suggested below should work. If not, you have a much more difficult problem and I'm not 100% sure it's even solvable.)

Comment: Also, I just created the [tag:proof-of-possession] tag. I think we should have one.

Answer (score 1):

Easy enough:

- Take B and hash it with a cryptographically secure hash function; for example, `K := SHA256( B )`

Background: a hash function takes an arbitrary length string, such as your file B, and converts it into a short (256 bit) string in such a way that someone without guessing B can guess what that string is [1].  There are a number of secure hash functions; SHA-256 is a popular one.

- Take A and encrypt it with the value K; for example, `Ciphertext := AES-GCM(K, A)`

Background: encryption converts a file (such as A) into a form such that, without knowledge of the key (K), no one can get any information about A (other than its size - you could disguise that by, say, padding all files to the maximum length; that's generally costly enough that we don't bother).  There are a number of secure encryption algorithms, AES-GCM is a popular one.

Most crypto packages should give you access to both hashing and encryption based on a key.

[1]: Actually, that's not how a cryptographer would explain it; it has a number of security properties beyond that; however that's what you need.

Comment: A possible drawback of this scheme is that knowing *K* is sufficient to decrypt *A* (but not sufficient to reconstruct *B*). Thus, someone in possession of *B* can compute *K* and distribute it to other parties, allowing those parties to then decrypt *A* without possessing (or even having any feasible way to acquire) *B*. If the OP does *not* want that, the problem gets (AFAICT) considerably more difficult to solve.

Answer (score 1):

Using the hash of the file $B$ to create an encryption key is a simple way to prove knowledge of its contents before providing decryption access to the file $A$, but there are some important details to consider.

**Issues:**

1. Say someone has access to a large portion of $B$ but not the whole thing. The entirety of $B$ may be unguessable, but if some of $B$ is known, the unknown portion may be short or predictable enough to be guessed. If so, a correct guess could be confirmed by seeing if a key derived from the known part of $B$ and a guess for the remaining part $G_i$ succeeds in decrypting the file $A$. It may be very efficient to make guesses $K_i = H(B \space || \space G_i)$ which then lead to a sensible decryption result. This would violate your requirement that no part of $B$ can be recovered from the encrypted $A$.
2. The use of a plain hash function, instead of a construction like HMAC, would leave the system open to known [vulnerabilities](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/20301/289428). So let's assume from this point forward we'll use something like HMAC. Relying on the unguessability of $B$ for the confidentiality of $A$ seems dangerous, since there's no guarantee that an arbitrary file will by itself contain an adequate amount of entropy to derive key material.
3. There should be some [context information](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/66969/what-is-meant-by-domain-separation-in-the-context-of-kdf), and [preprocessing of inputs](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18328/canonicalization-output-encoding), used along with a hash function to prevent issues where derived keys are reusable in illegitimate contexts.

**Potential Solutions:**

Require someone in possession of $B$ (a **prover**) to prove complete knowledge of $B$ before you (a **verifier**) give access to information $C$ which is used to derive the encryption key $K_A$ for file $A$. Below is one possible way to do this:

$K_A = HMAC('ContextForEncryptionKeyForFileA' \space || \space B, \space key=C)$

$W_{prover} = HMAC('ContextForProverChallengeBA' \space || \space T_{prover} \space || \space I_{prover} \space || \space B, \space key=R_{prover})$

The **prover** sends the **verifier** a timestamp $T_{prover}$ with adequate granularity, a random 32-byte token $R_{prover}$, optionally some identity information $I_{prover}$ like a username or even a public key, and the hash result $W_{prover}$.

The **verifier** can then check to see if the timestamp is valid: $T_{verifier} > T_{prover}$; and that it was created recent enough: $T_{verifier} - T_{prover} < Threshold$. Then it may be possible for the **verifier** to ensure the **prover** has adequate permission to request decryption access to $A$ using the identity information $I_{prover}$. If everything checks out, the **verifier** then checks to see if $W_{prover} = W_{verifier}$ using a [timing-safe](https://sqreen.github.io/DevelopersSecurityBestPractices/timing-attack/python) comparison and its own knowledge of $B$.

If the **verifier**'s results are the same as the **prover**'s, then the **prover** is given the key $C$, which could be 32 random bytes. If not, then the connection is terminated, and the **verifier** could keep track of how many failed attempts for decryption access to file $A$ were initiated by the **prover** associated with identity $I_{prover}$.

**Final Comments:**

This is an incomplete overview of a potential protocol which you could use to solve your problem.

Very importantly, it's missing the specifics for how the communication channels between **prover** and **verifier** are [secured and authenticated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_channel). Similarly, if $I_{prover}$ is used to implement access controls, it would be important to also verify the **prover** is the legitimate entity associated with that identity.

In regards to the use of hash functions and $HMAC$. It's prudent to not just concatenate inputs together, but to encode them prior to hashing so as to mitigate [canonicalization attacks](https://soatok.blog/2021/07/30/canonicalization-attacks-against-macs-and-signatures/). One simple way this is done is to count the number of inputs, measure the length of each input in order, then concatenate the inputs and prepend the metadata you just calculated. This helps ensure no potentially exploitable, or error inducing, unintended significance can be attributed to the inputs.