# Is SHA256 resistant to second preimage attack?

Tags: hash, sha-256

I am looking into building a merkle tree algorithm and I need to know if SHA256 is resistant to second preimage attack.

Answer (score 2):

SHA-256 has no known collision attack and has no known second pre-image attack and has no known pre-image attack.

There was a claim [Has SHA256 been broken by Treadwell Stanton DuPont?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/74251/18298) but is has already debunked.

Currently, we have generic attacks: $2^{256}$ pre-image resistance, $2^{256}$ secondary pre-image resistance and $2^{128}$ collision resistance. Collision resistance is lower due to the birthday attack. The academical attacks are [on reduced rounds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-2#Cryptanalysis_and_validation), therefore not practical, yet.

**Note per comment:**  It is not SHA-256 or any other Cryptographic hash's weakness. It is a problem with hash trees that enables to find secondary pre-images and it can be mitigated with domain separation as mentioned in [rfc6992](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6962#section-2.1). You can also see this problem in this post;

- [What is the reason to separate domains in the internal hash algorithm of a merkle tree hash?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/43430/18298)

Comment: Thank you. Furthermore do I have to take into account that leaf nodes and the internal 
nodes have different hashes like for example it is done for sha-1?As explained here https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/2097/how-does-a-tiger-tree-hash-handle-data-whose-size-isnt-a-power-of-two/2103#2103

Comment: are you asking adding 1 and 0 for domain separation?

Comment: Yes I am asking about adding data to make the leafs and the nodes different. Do we have to do that for sha256?

Comment: That is a different question and you can find the [answer here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/43434/18298)